# TYPO3 additional field in `tt_content` should be only displayed for a specific extension

Tags: typo3

TYPO2 10.4.14

In the below example of `addToAllTCAtypes` the third parameter is empty. This parameter should be make it possible, that only for a specific TCA type the field would be visible.

For extensions the type is list and an additional list_type is specifying the extension.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
 'tt_content',
 'tx_album_link',
 '',
 'after:header'
);
```

What I have to write into this third parameter, that the field is only visible for the specific extension?

Comment: This will only work if you define a new type for the tx_album extension. From the description, you are likely better off using a displayCond for this field and defining a condition that only shows the field when the extension is set in list_type, som thing along the lines of  'displayCond' => 'FIELD:list_type:=:ty_album',  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Columns/Properties/DisplayCond.html?highlight=displaycond

Answer (score 1):

Thanks the help I found the following solution:

```
// Feld definieren
$tempColumns = [
    'tx_album_link' => [
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:list_type:=:album_showalbum',
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'link',
        'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'itemsProcFunc' => 'HGA\\Album\\UserFunc\\TcaProcFunc->getLink',
        ],
    ],
];

// Feld der allgemeinen Datensatzbeschreibung hinzufügen - noch keine Ausgabe im Backend!
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content', 
    $tempColumns
    );

// Feld einer neuen Palette hinzufügen 
/*

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
        'tt_content',
        'general',
        'tx_album_link',
        'after:subheader'
        ); */

// Neue Palette dem Tag hinzufügen, nach dem Titel - Dadurch Anzeige im Backend
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
 'tt_content',
 'tx_album_link',
 '',
 'after:header'
);
```

I only had to add the `displayCond` line to the field definition. That's all!